# Android WebView shows unexpected Status code 407

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I am developing an application where I want to load a webpage. The application works fine with link starting with "https://" but shows error with link starting with "http://". The error is "unexpected Status code: 407". Can not figure out what is wrong. How is it possible to  load url starting with "http://" in WebView.
My code for WebView is mentioned below:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.showLive);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


    myWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    myWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);

    myWebView.setInitialScale(10);

    myWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
startWebView("your url");

private void startWebView(String url) {

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
                //dislpay your progress dialog
            }
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // dismiss progress dialog
            }
        });

        // Javascript inabled on webview
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Other webview options
        /*
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        */

        //Load url in webview
        webView.loadUrl(url);

    }
```